# python import error-class from different package not loading

Tags: python, python-2.7, setup.py

I am using python 2.7.5. I created a simple python project `pythontest`. The folder structure of my project is as follows:

```
pythontest
        |   
        -setup.py
        -README.md
        -src
            |
             -- pack1
                 |
                  test1.py
                  test2.py
            |
             --pack2
                |
                 test3.py
```

My files are like this:

test1.py

```
print "hello"
```

test2.py

```
import test1
import src.pack2.test3
print "hai"
```

test3.py

```
print "how are you?"
```

I did run the like this :

```
sudo python setup.py install
python src/pack1/test2.py
```

But i am getting the following error:

```
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/pack1/test2.py", line 7, in <module>
    import src.pack2.test3
ImportError: No module named pack2.test3
```

But i can run the code from eclipse. What is wrong with my code?
setup.py file is as follows:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup
def read(fname):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()

setup(
    name = "pythontest",
    version = "0.0.4",
    author = "Andrew Carter",
    author_email = "andrewjcarter@gmail.com",
    description = ("An demonstration of how to create, document, and publish "
                                   "to the cheese shop a5 pypi.org."),
    license = "BSD",
    keywords = "example documentation tutorial",
    url = "http://packages.python.org/an_example_pypi_project",
    packages=[],
    long_description=read('README.md'),
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
        "Topic :: Utilities",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License",
    ],
)
```

Comment: Having to use `import src.pack2.test` already shows that something is broken. You shouldn't need to mention `src` in the imports. The imports should look like `import pack2.test`. Also: you are using a relative import inside `test2.py` (the `import test1`). *This is bad*. Either use a relative import (`from . import test1`) or use an absolute import (`import pack1.test1 as test1`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to place `__init__.py`-files into packages (in your case, src, pack1 and pack2) for this to work. Also, you should get rid of src as package-name (it's generic and makes no sense), but instead use something pertaining to your actual codebase, e.g. supercoolapp or amazinglib or whatever you are writing on.

Then you need to add that top-level package to your packages-list in the setup.py.

Comment: i changed the code as u said, but still im getting the same error.